How is the end of a NEXRAD volume scan found using Py-ART?
I am working with NEXRAD volume scans that are built from level-2 chunks (s3://unidata-nexrad-level2-chunks/).
When concatenating the chunks into a single volume scan, how do I know when the end of the volume scan has occurred? I have looked into the API and I can find information on the last rays of sweeps, etc but nothing on the volume scan as a whole.
Radar.get_end(sweep) seems like it would work but I would need to know the total sweeps in a volume scan, and that does not seem possible either. This is the closest I could get while looking in the API at https://arm-doe.github.io/pyart/API/
